# AsyncStorage returns [Object] [Object]

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm tinkering with using JSON web token for authentication at the moment, between a react-native app and an `express/passport-jwt` server.

I can check credentials/login from the app to server no problem and as the key is returned from `server to app`, I can `console.log(response.token)` it on the app console.

I then save it with `AsyncStorage.setItem('JWT_Key', response.token)`

My issue is that when I return it using something like `console.log(AsyncStorage.getItem('JWT_Key'))` it returns `[Object] [Object]`

I can't seem to see anything in the docs, can someone tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AsyncStorage returns a promise, but you can also just grab the item through a callback:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('JWT_Key', (err, item) => console.log(item));
```

Comment: I still get the same [object object] even in the call back. Would you mind providing an example where you setItem with the key and then getItem with the key, so I can see it? My key is something like '@appSettings' but it's giving me such a hard time.